# Exporting geojson layer to file

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, export

I want to export the feature properties of a layer created with a function that takes the input of a user and then loops trough the .js file and creates a layer of markers, that correspond to the `features.propertie.pt`.
What I am failing to understand is how to pass the object created and the name of the file to the `saveToFile` function.
I have searched but couldn´t quiet find a solution that fits my needs.

I have a button with the following code that calls the "getPt" function:

```
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-grey w3-mobile w3-round-large w3-button w3-teal" onclick="getPt()">Go</button>
```

When the following function is called, it loops trough the js file and creates a layer of points that have a `feature.propertie.pt` that corresponde to the "`userInput`".

```
function getPt(){
    let input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var randomColor = generateRandomColor()
    var pt = L.geoJson(data,{
  
      filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return (feature.properties.pt === input);
      },
          pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
          return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 3, 
              fillOpacity: 2, 
              color: 'black', 
              fillColor: 'lightblue', 
              weight: 1,})
          },
      }  
      ); // end json layer ok
      lpt.addOverlay(pt, input);
};
```

I have another button with the following code to call the `saveToFile` function:

```
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-grey w3-mobile w3-round-large w3-button w3-teal" onclick="saveToFile()">Export PT</button>
```

I am using the FileSaver.min.js library and the function I´m calling is the following:

```
function saveToFile(content, input) {
  var file = filename + '.geojson';
  saveAs(new File([JSON.stringify(content)], file, {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  }), file);
}
```

What would be the proper way to get the object properties and userInput value and send it to the `saveToFile` function?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to save/download GeoJSON of `lpt` layer? What's also not clear is that your function `saveToFile(content, input)` has two parameters, of which second is not used at all and function call is without any parameters `onclick="saveToFile()`.

Comment: Hi TomazicM. Yes in fact the lpt layer will have added all the overLays created when getPt() function is called. The second parameter I intended to use it, if I want to save only one of the layers. But how can I pass to the  function saveToFile the name which will be the filename? If I dont pass parameters I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: filename is not defined".. So If I want to save the file with a particular ("userInput").value, how can I do that?

Comment: Have filename stored in some global variable/object, and then you can access it in your function. But this is not GIS question, but HTML/JS one and as such more suitable for StackOverflow site. But your main question is about getting GeoJSON layer content?

Comment: Yes how to export to a file the contents of the created layer. And because I´m using leaflet to create a map with points and I´m working with GIS content I thought here would be the place.. But refrasing my previousanswer: "You are right, function call is without parameters. In fact the lpt layer will have added all the overLays created when getPt() function is called. 
I manage to download with the filename so far, but it comes empty. meaning I´m failing to pass the objects."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.toGeoJSON` layer group method (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) to get GeoJSON object from `lyr` GeoJSON layer:

```
function saveToFile() {
  var geoJSON = lpt.toGeoJSON();
  var file = filename + '.geojson';
  saveAs(new File([JSON.stringify(geoJSON)], file, {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  }), file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, it worked like a charm!